# I would like to extract and list the cron jobs printed from a server right next to each cron job

Tags: ruby, cron, chef-infra

I'm trying to print a list of all the servers that are affected by cron job recipes in chef and I would like to have the cron time value printed next to each cron job for a specific server.

I have already used a script like this:

```
for i in $(ls cookbooks/cookbook_name/recipes); 
    do knife search node "recipes:*${i%.*}" -i; 
done
```

I want to extract the `crontab` time from an expression like this:

```
% frequent zfs snapshot
  cron_d 'zfs-auto-snapshot-frequently' do
  minute '*/15'
  path PATH
  command '/opt/zfs-auto-snapshot.sh frequent 6'
end
% Hourly
cron_d 'zfs-auto-snapshot-hourly' do
  minute '59'
  path PATH
  command '/opt/zfs-auto-snapshot.sh hourly 4'
end
% Daily
cron_d 'zfs-auto-snapshot-daily' do
  minute '59'
  hour '23'
  path PATH
  command '/opt/zfs-auto-snapshot.sh daily 3'
end
% Weekly
cron_d 'zfs-auto-snapshot-weekly' do
  minute '0'
  hour '0'
  weekday '1'
  path PATH
  command '/opt/zfs-auto-snapshot.sh weekly 1'
end
% Monthly
cron_d 'zfs-auto-snapshot-monthly' do
  minute '0'
  hour '0'
  day '1'
  path PATH
  command '/opt/zfs-auto-snapshot.sh monthly 1'
end
```

#### I need a list output sort of like this:

admindb.xyz.com  ***3*

server.xyz.com  ***3*

office.xyz.com  *2***

collector01.xyz.com  *3*4*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really possible short of making a ton of assumptions about your code and writing some terrible regexes. Chef is code, static analysis of any code is hard, with Ruby it's somewhere between infuriating and "lolno". Best bet would be to not even look at Chef and directly query each machine via SSH.

Comment: You could possibly do something horrible with tags, but I agree with coderanger completely.